# Azure MessagingException: Server randomly unable to process ReceiveAsync

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

I am getting a repetitive error just listening for a service bus message. There doesn't have to be any messaging traffic coming through. Every 30 seconds I am checking for a cancellation. This happens in a task and there are several listening tasks running simultaneously:

```
System.Exception: AutoEventManager messaging error 2 since 03:10:45 AM with clientId 0d0815ab-ed35-4bd4-9df9-fdbf6d613053. See inner exception. 
---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
---> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingException: The server was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. If the problem persists, please contact your Service Bus administrator and provide the tracking id. TrackingId:9633ee13-27b4-4ffd-8a2c-8096cad90df0_G18, Timestamp:5/5/2015 11:05:02 AM 
---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: The server was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. If the problem persists, please contact your Service Bus administrator and provide the tracking id. TrackingId:9633ee13-27b4-4ffd-8a2c-8096cad90df0_G18, Timestamp:5/5/2015 11:05:02 AM Server stack trace: 
     at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.ThrowIfFaultMessage(Message wcfMessage) 
     at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.HandleMessageReceived(IAsyncResult result) Exception rethrown at [0]: at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) 
     at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.DuplexCorrelationAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r) 
     at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result) Exception rethrown at [1]: 
     at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result) 
     at
```

Here is the code up to actual processing of the message which all runs just fine.

```
    public void AddAsyncListener(string clientId)
    {
        var cToken = _cSource.Token;

        _mgrTasks.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Task>(clientId, Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                var errCount = 0;
                var errTimer = DateTime.Now;
                var cfgSvc = _ioc.GetInstance<IClientConfigService>();
                var conString = cfgSvc.GetNeoBusConString(clientId);

                var cmdFilter = new SqlFilter(String.Format("MessageType <> {0}",
                    (int)MessageTypeEnum.Progress));

                var namespaceMgr = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(conString);


                if (!namespaceMgr.SubscriptionExists(clientId, "LogManager"))
                    namespaceMgr.CreateSubscription(clientId, "LogManager", cmdFilter);

                var cmdClient = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(conString, clientId, "LogManager");

                var logEventService = _ioc.GetInstance<ILogEventService>();

                logEventService.SetScope(clientId);

                while (!cToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var message = cmdClient.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Result;

                        if (message == null) continue;
{rest of message processing here}
```

Oh, the application that handles these tasks is also running in Azure as a Cloud Service.

It doesn't *seem* to be having any terrible effects and I am trapping them and simply retrying the ReceiveAsync which is usually successful. I'm just not in the habit of ignoring intermittent errors...

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

According to this MSDN response, this is *okay*...

> Most of the failures are transient, please make sure you haven't turned off client retry. Client retry will automatically retry in the case of transient failures. You can find more on retry policy at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.retrypolicy.aspx
>
> High number of CommunicationExceptions might be due to a bad network or clients running out of resources like high CPU, thread count, or memory. You can start by looking at those first.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/368a11eb-aacf-4d82-84bf-03e317baf779/dailyhourly-messagingcommunicationexception-and-messagingexceptions?forum=servbus